# Transactional IBM MQ 9.0.0.3 .NET Monitor sample crashes with AMQ8377

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, ibm-mq

I'm trying to get the transactional .NET monitor sample to work from the IBM WebSphere 9.0 documentation (see Using the .NET monitor, page 675 of the folowing document: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/docs/V9.0/PDFs/mq90.develop.pdf)

I managed to compile everything ok (targetting .NET 2.0), but when running the monitor with runmqdnm as follows, I get an exception:

```
runmqdnm -m myqmgr -q myqueue -a TransactionalMonitor.dll -c TransactionalMonitor.Monitor 
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2017.
AMQ8377: Unexpected error 2354 was received by the application.
```

I'm running the sample directly on my MQ server, which is a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine with IBM MQ 9.0.0.3 server installed.

For reference, the code I implemented:

```
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using IBM.WMQ;
using IBM.WMQMonitor;

[assembly: ApplicationName("TransactionalMonitor")]

namespace TransactionalMonitor
{
    [Transaction(TransactionOption.Required)]
    public class Monitor : ServicedComponent, IMQObjectTrigger
    {
        [AutoComplete(true)]
        public void Execute(MQQueueManager qmgr, MQQueue queue, MQMessage message, string param)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("SETTING COMMIT");
            ContextUtil.SetComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

When removing the transactional stuff the sample works OK.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference:
Problem is fixed after upgrading to version 9.0.5.
Also make sure that the MSRPC & MSDTC ports are not blocked by a firewall.
See [this blog post](https://fairwaytech.com/2012/12/distributed-transaction-coordinators-port-135-and-firewalls-oh-my/) for more info on the that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what release of IBM MQ you are actually using (you mention MQ V9 documentation).

I would compile your exit with the OLDEST release of .NET that you have.  People try and use the latest & greatest but most times it will not work.

i.e. For 64-bit DLL

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /nologo /t:library /platform:x64 /r:System.dll /r:"%MQ_FILE_PATH%\bin\amqmdnet.dll" /out:TransactionalMonitor.dll TransactionalMonitor.cs
```

Comment: MQ version is 9.0.0.3.  I tried compiling the program on the command line like you suggested (I had to add an extra reference amdmdnm.dll), but with the same results. `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /nologo /t:library /platform:x64 /r:System.dll /r:"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin\amqmdnet.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin\amqmdnm.dll" /out:TransactionalMonitor.dll TransactionalMonitor.cs`

Comment: I would open a PMR with IBM and ask them why it is not working given you are using what is in the MQ Knowledge Center (aka manual).